Is there a way to provide values for columns separately in COPY command while loading from parquet file to redshift
I have a parquet file which I need to load into Redshift.
I'm using COPY command to do that.
But there are also other columns in the table which needs to have values inserted along with the COPY command.
The parquet file doesn't contain the value for those 2 columns - schema_id and timestamp
How do I provide values for two columns along with the COPY command itself while loading the data from parquet file.
COPY table_name from "s3_location/parquetfile.parquet" IAM_ROLE "iam_role"
Update: 13-Sept-2024 16:11 IST
I created a table with default values thinking that I can replace them later after loading the data into other columns of the table.
In this case, it was saying num of columns mismatched 52 in parquet file vs 54 in table (with 2 extra default value columns)
If I provide the column names to copy command table, and also the default columns it is throwing ERROR: DEFAULT columns are currently unsupported for this format if not included in the column list

No, that exceeds what COPY can do. You need a proper ETL process for that.

COPY lets you specify which columns you do have in the file and import only those, while leaving the rest to be filled out by default (also generated in Postgres but not Redshift), values on the fly. You can replace them later via update.
demo at db<>fiddle
create table table_name(
   a float
  ,b float
  ,c float generated always as ( |/(a^2+b^2) ) stored
  ,schema_id text default 'a_schema'
  ,"timestamp" timestamp default now()
);

COPY table_name(a,b) from '/tmp/example_file.csv' 
  (format csv, delimiter ';');

select*from table_name;




a
b
c
schema_id
timestamp




92.38
47.45
103.85358395356417
a_schema
2024-09-12 21:40:34.999555


18.61
25.92
31.908909414143256
a_schema
2024-09-12 21:40:34.999555


19.83
19.76
27.99440122595945
a_schema
2024-09-12 21:40:34.999555


25.99
30.16
39.81338593990719
a_schema
2024-09-12 21:40:34.999555


34.1
38.81
51.66261801341469
a_schema
2024-09-12 21:40:34.999555



If you need a copy that joins multiple files, it can't, but you can just run two copies for them and join the resulting tables. Alternatively, you can let copy read from program and use external commands to merge them while feeding the output as copy input.
As you pointed out, a considerable downside is this leaves you stuck with those defaults. Redshift doesn't offer alter table..alter column..[set|drop] default clauses to get rid of them later. A column created with a default from the start, can't be changed::

You can't alter columns with default values.

What you can do instead is leave them without a default value entirely (copy will leave them with a null), load only the columns you have, then update afterwards:
create table table_name(
   a float
  ,b float
  ,c float
  ,schema_id text
  ,"timestamp" timestamp
);

COPY table_name(a,b) from '/tmp/example_file.csv' 
  (format csv, delimiter ';');

update table_name set c           = |/(a^2+b^2)
                     ,schema_id   = 'a_schema'
                     ,"timestamp" = now();


I have like 100s of tables, I want to provide different schema_id and timestamp values for all those tables for every execution of COPY command on them. Is there a way to achieve this? I tried setting a default value before executing the COPY command and resetting it back after execution. But it seems like Redshift doesn't support updating the default value for a column by altering it.

@PoreddySivaSukumarReddyUS You're right, Redshift doesn't seem to doesn't even have alter table..alter column..[set|drop] default clauses, and openly says:: "You can't alter columns with default values.". What you can do instead is leave them without a default value entirely, load only the columns you have, and then update table_name set schema_id='manually_set_default',timestamp=now(); afterwards.

Updated the question with more details.
